# non-zero minimum value of score field in solr

Tags: solr

I implemented a query parser which does some score adjustment which is essentially demoting by multiplying a very small number (1E-20) or something. I found that the score returned from this is 0.0. I guess score field in solr is float or double type in JAVA? Anybody knows the smallest non-zero value in score field of SOLR?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is rounded to 0 in score field. Probably this is because score type is float but internally double type is used?